# Rules of Thumb in GDI+

Tags: .net, graphics, gdi+

I have been working on some GDI+ code in .NET and have been learning my lessons the hard way. Simple things like:

- What looks good on screen may not look nice on paper and vice versa
- Caching too many objects can result in an OutOfMemoryException
- Floats aren't exact

...and so on. I'm sure there is a lot more that experienced folk can add to this.

What are some good rules to follow when using GDI+ or any graphics library in general?

One useful tip per post will be nice. Thanks.

Comment: [Hard limits for XY values in GDI+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468495)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create objects as late as possible (Don't prematurely optimize/cache) and release them as early as possible (calling Dispose or wrapping in using statement if IDisposable).

Answer (score 2):

Dont avoid using unmanaged calls, it can speed things up a lot when done correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Careful when you transform between logical/screen coordinates. If done at the wrong time you can run out of precision and get some nasty drawing artifacts in return.

The last time this bit me, I was trying to calculate a new point in logical coordinates; those were already near the limit of precision though, so the new point was not quite what one would hope. Transforming sooner fixed it.

It is possible to get a similar problem by transforming to screen coordinates too soon, although an API which allows you to pass it floating point coordinates (which GDI+ does) tends to be much more robust against that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't draw more than you have to.

In general, drawing operations are more expensive than other calculations you'll be performing (especially in GDI+, which is a nice API but not the fastest drawing library ever). Spending a bit more time in your own code to avoid unnecessary drawing operations (eg. drawing the same thing more than once) is often well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

GDI Gotchas that have burned me a few times.

- Clone doesn't clone() the underlying data clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat) does.  So if you dispose of a clone(), the original object becomes unusable.  Use new Bitmap() if you want two seperate bitmaps.
- If you load an image FromFile that file is locked until the bitmap is disposed of (can't even be read).
- When using DrawImage don't forget to set SmoothingMode, InterpolationMode and PixelOffsetMode or you will be surprised by the low quality of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly a GDI+ issue but remember this to save yourself a few hours of debugging:

One mistake I've made too often using GDI+ in .NET is to call `Matrix` methods on the `Transform` property of the `Graphics` object. Example (in C++/CLI):

```
g->Transform->Translate(100.0f, 250.0f);    // WRONG. Will not have any effect.
```

The getter of the `Transform` property only returns a *copy* of the matrix. So any methods called on this copy will not affect the value of the graphics transform. To manipulate the graphics transform, call one of the wrapper methods (`MultiplyTransform`, `TranslateTransform`, `ScaleTransform`, etc.) as shown below.

```
g->TranslateTransform(100.0f, 250.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful how you use regions: http://steveperks.com/post/Fun-With-GDI2b-Bugs.aspx