# GDI+ draws ellipse horizontally flipped with large coordinate values

Tags: c#, vb.net, gdi+

I have a control that contains shapes drawn with GDI+ and the user can zoom into it. If he zooms in far the actual coordinates that the shapes are drawn at get quite large.

Now I zoomed into the location of the left edge of a circle drawn by `FillEllipse` and after a while the circle suddenly flips and I actually see a right edge instead of a left edge.

I extracted the coordinates and put up a simple program that reproduces the problem (All thats needed for it is a form, with two radiobuttons and a picturebox of sufficient size on it):

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Draw()
        'Create a canvas
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.Clear(Color.Black)

            'X location, Y location and the diameter of the circle to draw
            Dim x, y, dia As Single

            If RadioButton1.Checked Then
                'This works as expected
                x = 561
                y = -3993174.7
                dia = 7986931.0
            Else
                'This comes out flipped
                x = 561
                y = -4436903.7
                dia = 8874368.0
            End If

            'Define and draw the ellipse
            Dim rectf As New RectangleF(x, y, dia, dia)
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, rectf)
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.LightGreen, rectf)
            'Mark the circle's vertical center
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 0.0F, y + dia / 2, CSng(bmp.Width), y + dia / 2)
        End Using

        'Display the image
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
        'Redraw on radiobutton check change
        Draw()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Draw()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

In the images below the **red** part is the ellipse that is being drawn, **black** is the background, and the **blue** line is the vertical center of the ellipse as calculated from the coordinates I put in.

If you run that program and select `RadioButton1` you will see the following:

[image]

All is well, the circle is drawn to the right.

However if you select `RadioButton2` you see:

[image]

The circle suddenly is flipped horizontally and is drawn to the left.

I suspect that somehow the large values interfere but I honestly can't see a reason how this outcome can be produced.
Can someone shed some light why GDI+ gets upset and how I can fix it?

Both answers in VB.NET and in C# are very much appreciated.

Comment: maybe it is an issue of contrast, but I cant see any circle at all, just a petite blue line and a garishly bright red background.

Comment: @Plutonix: I believe that the ellipse is the red part. It's just so large that the curvature is basically undetectable visually.

Comment: Yes that is true. The red part is the ellipse that is being drawn. I probably should have pointed that out more, as it is only apparent from the code I posted.

Comment: GDI+ indeed has plenty of overflow issues, only practical approach is to limit how deeply you zoom in.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23255170/2330053) indicates a similar problem: "Interestingly though when the Y value got too large (but less than suggested positive value of 1,073,741,951) the resulting line went from being drawn down as expected (to a Y pixel location greater than my last reasonable point) to being drawn up (to the top of the window)."

Comment: By the way, your comments in the code about which portion draws correct/flipped are backwards:  RadioButton1 draws correctly, while RadioButton2 draws flipped.

Comment: Other than the admittedly vague "sounds like overflow" answer, I don't have anything specific to offer. However, I will note that `2^31 / 8874368.0` is `241.9872`, and that many displays are configured at 120dpi, making the number `241.9872`, which is very close to `120 * 2`, a very intriguing coincidence. In any case, the true solution is that you will need to pre-scale your rendering to ensure you don't exceed GDI+'s coordinate system limits.

Comment: @Idle_Mind You're correct, I already had changed the comments in my VS code but somehow forget to transfer it. Your other answer is also very interesting. I think I will implement a boundary system for the shapes (which are by the way part of a 2D plot control as well ;-)) to avoid large coordinates. Using reasonably large bounds won't change the appearance anyways.