# drawing point in c# windows form

Tags: c#, draw, point

Visual studio says there is an OverflowException unhandled

```
//draws the point.
public void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    float radius = 3; //radius of the circle which describes the point.

    // draws the circle of the point, with parameters of the square which bounds the circle.
    g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black, 6F), float.Parse((this.X - radius).ToString()), float.Parse((this.Y - radius).ToString()), 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
}
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the result of `ToString()` here? Or to put that a different way, what is the type of `this.X` and `this.Y` that is causing you to need to do that?

Comment: the X,Y were double, but the g object takes float type parameters. I found the problem. thank you for helping! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're ending up with point values outside graphic boundaries.  check your this.X and this.Y values.  see [What are the hard bounds for drawing coordinates in GDI+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468495/what-are-the-hard-bounds-for-drawing-coordinates-in-gdi)

Comment: Yes, this is what it was, the x and y are taking big values that cannot be drawn in my screen. thank you!! :)